# Login takes long to load on wake

Tags: windows-11, login-screen

On waking laptop it takes 15-20 seconds for login field to appear, this is a brand new laptop 11th Gen i5-11400H @ 2.70 GHz with 16 GB DDR4. Is this normal for Windows 11?

Windows 10 was a lot snappier soon as you moved mouse or woke the laptop you're instantly ready to login with your password.

[image: Annotated login screen]

Comment: Make sure you are using plain Suspend and not Hybrid Sleep.  It may be hibernating on you. If you have a slow hard drive, it may take a long time to load.

Comment: I don't have Hybrid sleep looks like they took that out in Win11 I checked in Power Options in Control Panel. Is it because hard drive is set to sleep at 15 mins? I don't get why it would be slow it's a SSD 512GB NVMe/PCIe M.2

Comment: I find the screen faster to appear if I click on the login line (or just near it).